# Can I somehow create a fee that i will receive?

Tags: solidity, fees

I want to charge the user a fee evertime he does something with my smart contract, can I do this?

Would be nice if someone can explain it to me with this example:
Everytime someone calls a function(in this example a increment or decrement function) he needs to pay a fee to me.

```
contract Counter {
    uint256 public count;

    address public Owner;

    event Increment(uint256 value);
    event Decrement(uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        count = 0;
    }

    function increment() public {
        count += 1;
        emit Increment(count);
    }

    function decrement() public {
        count -= 1;
        emit Decrement(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a require statement to each function, such as `require(msg.value > 1000)`. You will need a way for you to withdraw the funds stored on the contract to your private wallet as well.

Comment: i get an error: 'Error: processing response error ... Transaction reverted without a reason.'

Comment: Correct answer, 2 additional things: The msg.value is in Wei and the function should be payable :)

Comment: Have that but still error

Comment: Add that in another question or modify ur question with the new code @robinnlmn